# OAuth error when using Okta Authentication in ionic app

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, okta

I am getting following error when integrating okta authentication in my application.

```
OAuthError
{
    name: “OAuthError”,
    message: “The ‘{0}’ system claim could not be evaluated.”,
    errorCode: “server_error”,
    errorSummary: “The ‘{0}’ system claim could not be evaluated.”}
    errorCode:"server_error"
    errorSummary:"The ‘{0}’ system claim could not be evaluated."
    message:"The ‘{0}’ system claim could not be evaluated." 
    name:“OAuthError”
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using this blog post to integrate Ionic and Okta? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/22/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication

Comment: Can you show the outgoing request? You can use a tool like Fiddler or Charles to see the request that is sent to the `/authorize` endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received the same error using the OpenID Connect sign on method for a custom application. In my case, the fix was to make sure the username attribute was properly set on the assigned application for the user in question.

Comment: So is there some way to add all of your users in the organization to an app and have it assign all of their user names to match their email addresses automatically??? Would we have to script that via the Okta API? For orgs with 100s or 1000s of users that need to be added to a new app, this seems a little crazy.

Answer (score 8):

+1 with Assil
Error Code is

```
"The 'sub' system claim could not be evaluated."
```

By Default the Usernames, even the Users are Assigned to Applications is Blank. And we have to add them manually.
I am checking if that can be done Programatically to avoid manual interventions, will share here.

Add Username
[image: Add Username]

Edit Username
[image: Edit Username]

Comment: Thanks to you both. This saved me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The message was

> **"The 'sub' system claim could not be evaluated."**

The resolution was as Cayce said. The application if assigned to a user, then that username must appear in the username attribute of the registered application.